# How to extract the non-dominated solutions (Pareto front)

Tags: matlab, function, solution

I have tried so many times to write the code of extracting the non-dominated (or dominated)

solutions  for two objective functions using MATLAB.

I have two simple objective functions:

J1=x.^2

J2=(x-2).^2

and I have a range for x values, say from -5 to 5 and there are, for example, 100 solutions to be

generated randomly within the range specified.

I want to extract the non-dominated solutions from these solutions.

I have no problem of all above operations. What I have done so far is:

```
   % generating 100 solutions randomly between -5 and 5:

   x=-5+10*rand(100,1);

   % calculate both objective functions, J1 and J2 at each solution:

   J1=x.^2;

   J2=(x-2).^2;
```

Now, I faced the problem of how to translate the concept to a written code.

I know the concept of how to extract the non-dominated solutions and Pareto front.

I can do it manually but this will take very long time.

I tried using if statements but the results were not accurate.

I think it is better to extract the indices of the dominated solutions and then remove them from

the main vector x to get the non-dominated solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you need: J1 and J2 are both increasing functions of x?! Seems a bit strange, doesn't it? Can you provide the ordering rule defining how you decide when one solution dominates the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mind files from FEX? [This one works perfectly: "Pareto Front" by Yi Cao](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17251-pareto-front)

giving you the indices of `x` of dominating solutions.

Then you just have to use it like this:

```
x=-5+10*rand(100,1);
J1=x.^2;
J2=(x-2).^2;

idx = paretofront([J1,J2]);
xdi = ~ismember(idx,1:numel(x));

figure(1)
hold on
scatter(J1,J2,10,'red');
scatter(J1(idx),J2(idx),50,'blue');
scatter(J1(xdi),J2(xdi),50,'green');
hold off

legend('all solutions','dominating solutions','non dominating solutions')
```

leads to:

[image]

which is exactly how it is supposed to look like. Otherwise you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Actually, this is a minimization problem. But we have to be aware of two objective functions not only one. We have to compare each solution with all other solutions and extract the non-dominated ones. The index of comparing is:
For a minimization problem, x1 dominates x2 when:
 J1(x1) is less than or equal J1(x2), and
 J2(x1) is less than  J2(x2)

Comment: I have tried using Yi Cao's code but it gave the following error:??? Error using ==> paretofront
Too many output arguments.

Comment: there was a little typo, and I added an example.

Comment: Hi, Yi Cao 's code has been removed from File Exchange, could you please help me to have this toolbox?  I need this toolbox. Thanks

Comment: @S.EB There will be a reason, it is removed. But there seem to be alternatives on FEX. See also [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/460426-yi-cao-s-pareto-front-toolbox-has-been-removed-from-from-file-exchange-can-i-find-this-toolbox-here).