# Search for median point in pareto front

Tags: matlab, sorting, mathematical-optimization

For the implementation of a classification procedure, I'm using a Pareto front to extract non-dominated samples. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17251-pareto-front gives me the Pareto front, but then the paper I'd like to implement calls for picking the median point! I tried a lot but I can't find a way to do this. I even thought about calculating de Euclidean distances to the origin but since I have my samples as in the figure, (0,0) isn't the origin! An extra problem is that this piece of code will be in a loop, so that it changes iteratively. It's thus impossible tot check manually each time wat the origin will be!

Has somebody an idea of how to extract the optimal (median) point of the Pareto front? With or without the technique of euclidean distances that I'm thinking about.

[image]

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20760209/3248346

Comment: @I.K. Not really, it gives me indeed a Pareto front, which I already had! It's just the search for the most optimal solution of the Pareto front...